# Zoneminder 404 upon installation

Tags: 12.04, apache2, webcam

I've run `sudo apt-get install zoneminder` on my clean install of Ubuntu 12.04. The installation downloaded about 120MB and there were no errors.

I then typed `sudo service zoneminder restart` and I can see that it shuts down and starts up zoneminder successfully.

I then navigate to `http://localhost` and I see the default Apache *It Works!*.

I then navigate to `http://localhost/zm` and I get a 404.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Did you setup proper file permissions?

Comment: I told you exactly what I did...

Comment: Try out the second comment in this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1379559)

Comment: Glad that it worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tweaking Apache configuration will solve this issue

```
sudo ln -s /etc/zm/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/zoneminder.conf 
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

Found this fix from [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/video_surveillance_zoneminder_ubuntu)